# Scatter plot of variables in a column of a tibble using dplyr & ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dplyr

I have the following tibble that would like to use to make a scatter plot (using ggplot2) of logcpm values of AA_Colon vs. BA_Colon matched by gene.

```
             gene   sample     logcpm
             <chr>    <chr>      <dbl>
 1 ENSG00000169903 AA_Colon 0.31536340
 2 ENSG00000145321 AA_Colon 0.19735593
 3 ENSG00000171560 AA_Colon 0.00000000
 4 ENSG00000171557 AA_Colon 0.19735593
 5 ENSG00000106327 AA_Colon 0.06882901
 6 ENSG00000228278 AA_Colon 0.13452328
 7 ENSG00000138115 AA_Colon 0.31536340
 8 ENSG00000148702 AA_Colon 0.00000000
 9 ENSG00000140107 AA_Colon 0.00000000
10 ENSG00000197723 AA_Colon 0.00000000
11 ENSG00000169903 BA_Colon 1.14724849
12 ENSG00000145321 BA_Colon 0.08113901
13 ENSG00000171560 BA_Colon 0.36654820
14 ENSG00000171557 BA_Colon 0.23088996
15 ENSG00000106327 BA_Colon 0.08113901
16 ENSG00000228278 BA_Colon 0.08113901
17 ENSG00000138115 BA_Colon 0.42987550
18 ENSG00000148702 BA_Colon 0.00000000
19 ENSG00000140107 BA_Colon 0.00000000
20 ENSG00000197723 BA_Colon 0.08113901
```

Currently, I'm doing (which works):

```
tibble %>%
    spread(key = sample, value = logcpm) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = AA_Colon, y = BA_Colon)) +
    geom_point()
```

But, I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to directly work with the tidy format and extract the two vectors to plot instead of spreading the data into two columns.

Comment: I think that is pretty elegant already. You transformed and plotted data in three lines of code...and they are clear in their function and purpose...that is a win!

Comment: The aesthetics in `ggplot` must be the same length of the data, so it's unclear to me how you would get this without spreading the data. I agree with @sconfluentus that this is elegant already. By the way, your code refers to `AF_Colon` and `BF_Colon`, while the data uses `BA_Colon` and `BF_Colon`, so it wouldn't work as is. It's always best to submit a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

When the data are in tidy format, ggplot gives scatterplot with just two columns of dots, one for AA_Colon and one for BA_Colon.

```
ggplot(tibble, aes(x = sample, y = logcpm)) + 
        geom_point()
```

Maybe boxplots with `geom_jitter` would be more useful.

```
ggplot(tibble, aes(x = sample, y = logcpm)) +
geom_boxplot() + 
geom_jitter(width = 0.3)
```

Comment: `colour=sample` could be useful too